# Not able to insert data into MsSQL using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to insert user data into MS SQL using JDBC, no matter how many ways I try searching for answers and keep changing the code I get either 2 of the below

1. HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
   Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [com.gmaps.web.SignUpcontroller]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.gmaps.web.SignUpcontroller]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gmaps.web.SignUpcontroller
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

2. this driver is not configured for integrated authentication JDBC SQL server

Comment: Here is my project structure. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So, one of your dependencies can't be found in your classpath. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gmaps.web.SignUpcontroller`.

Comment: Thank you, David, for the solution it's my bad I was calling the same page in different folders. But the second one still stays, I can't get rid of I looked into Microsoft docs and downloaded dll files but no use. I cant understand where I am going wrong.



I see this error as well : No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=UserData;integratedSecurity=true

Comment: Have you loaded the driver with `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  ` as per the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/working-with-a-connection?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes, I did. I even downloaded slqjdbc8.2 according to the MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/system-requirements-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

Java version is java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)

Comment: I get below error as 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
 at

Comment: I added 7.2.2 jre8 version as well in POM.xml file
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.2.jre8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>